# ForeignKey with a list of ApplicationUser objects

Tags: entity-framework-core

When it comes to a single object's foreign key, we would have a property:

SingleMap.cs

```
[ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
public int ApplicationUserID { get; set; }

public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

How do we map the foreignkey when we have a list of ApplicationUsers?

ManyMap.cs

```
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUserList { get; set; }
```

Comment: You would have the foreign key in a separate lookup table. Or you'd let EF core handle it for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

it is usually used this way:

```
public class ManyMap
{
public int ID  {get; set;}

.....

[InverseProperty(nameof(ApplicatonUser.ManyMap))]
public ICollection<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers{ get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser
{
 ......

public int ManyMapID { get; set; }

[ForeignKey(nameof(ManyMapID))]
[InverseProperty("ApplicationUsers")]
public ManyMap ManyMap { get; set; }
}
```